# Cumulative rental payments over a period of time

Tags: finance

What's the formula to figure out how much money you make on total rental payments over a period.

Say each month I rent out 2 cars, and get $50 for each. The length of the rental period is indefinite.

- Jan, 2 cars = $100, $100 total
- Feb, 2 cars = $100 + $100 for Jan's two cars, $200 total
- Mar, 2 cars = $100 + $100 for jans + $100 for Febs, $300 total

How do I do this in a formula if I wanted to calculate, say 4 a month, at $50 payments, over the next 23 months. How much would I make?

I'm stuck

Comment: If you don´t know the rental period of each car then you cannot calculate it.

Comment: I want to be able to calculate "for XX months, assuming I rent YY cars each month (the same), at ZZ rate, I'll have $$"